# How to update key in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray`

I want to make changes to a dictionary stored in the array

My `data.plist` looks like:

```
data Array
   Item 0 Dictionary
       imagename String
       name String
       text String
       url String
   Item 1 Dictionary
       imagename String
       name String
       text String
       url String
   Item 2 Dictionary
       imagename String
       name String
       text String
       url String
```

So I want to update key `imagename` and `name` in all items.

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the key and item, insert item with new key.

Comment: can you write how can i do that, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should about do it.

```
-(void)updateKey:(id)newKey oldKey:(id)oldKey atIndex:(int)index {
    [[_myArray objectAtIndex:index] removeObjectForKey:oldKey];
    [[_myArray objectAtIndex:index] setObject:forObject forKey:newKey]; 
}
```

Comment: so to update imagename in Item 0 i need to write [self updateKey:@"imagename" newKey:@"qqq" oldKey:@"imagename" atIndex:1] ?

Comment: Actually, I made a slight mistake in writing the method- the forObject parameter isn't needed.  I'll edit it to remove it.  To do what you want to do, it'd be [self updateKey:@"qqq" oldKey:@"imagename" atIndex:0];